# How to show and hide a view on button click

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have one `uiview` , `Button` .At initial my view will be hidden So when my button click I need to show my `uiview` and when I click same button I need to hide same view.

How to do that in swift 2.0.Now what I did is when I click first time - its showing.

```
@IBAction func PressRefine(sender: AnyObject) {
    menuView.hidden = false
}
```

But again when I press it should hide.
How to do that???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try an `if` statement.

```
@IBAction func PressRefine(sender: AnyObject) {
    if menuView.hidden {
        menuView.hidden = false
    } else {
        menuView.hidden = true
    }
}
```

or as @TedHuinink suggested, with less code.

```
@IBAction func PressRefine(sender: AnyObject) {
    menuView.hidden = !menuView.hidden
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `menuView.hidden = !menuView.hidden`

Answer (score 3):

first make view outlet

```
@IBOutlet weak var newpptview: UIView!  




@IBAction func newpresentation(_ sender: Any) {
            if newpptview.isHidden{
                newpptview.isHidden = false
            } else{
                newpptview.isHidden = true
            }
        }
```

its better that to all

OR

```
@IBAction func newpresentation(_ sender: Any) {
         newpptview.isHidden = !newpptview.isHidden
}
```

swift 3 and 4